# c# - Differences in delays experienced with HttpWebRequest exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm experiencing some very strange behaviour with a HttpWebRequest when it is handling a 500 server error.

In the code example below, you can assume that http://example.com/service.endpoint immediately returns a 500 server error when it is called.

When I run this code on my desktop PC (a standard x86 machine running Windows 7), the exception gets raised, I log it, and the method immediately completes. This is my desired behaviour.

When I run this code on a development server (a vmware guest machine on a seperate host, Xeon x64 running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard) the exception is immediately raised, but the method takes around 15 seconds to complete (following the exception being raised).

My question is - what could be causing the difference in behaviour observed between the two tests?

(Both methods the run conditions are the same - i.e. I'm not running the code from Visual Studio on my desktop - both were run within an identical service wrapper).

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.

```
    void MakeRequest(StringBuilder postParams)
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/service.endpoint");

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.KeepAlive = false;

        string postData = postParams.ToString();
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        req.Timeout = 10000;

        Console.WriteLine("Requested started.");

        var stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(postData);
        stOut.Close();

        WebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = req.GetResponse();

            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Deal with response here

            response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Request completed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (response != null) response.GetResponseStream().Close();
            req.Abort();
            Console.WriteLine("Exception with request raised: {0}", ex);
        }
        // Delay is observed between above "Exception with request.." and following line:
        Console.WriteLine("MakeRequest() has completed.");
    }
```

Edit: To make it clearer where delay exists

A heavily redacted version of the logs this call makes is shown below. It serves to show where the lions share of delay is observed on the server (this is not seen on my desktop):

```
2011-08-16 16:39:32,475 [STP OrderPool Thread #0] INFO   - Submitting quote to REDACTED
2011-08-16 16:39:32,490 [STP OrderPool Thread #0] INFO   - Invoking ASSEMBLY_NAME_REDACTED, Version=1.0.4245.27855, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null::REDACTED
2011-08-16 16:39:32,709 [STP OrderPool Thread #0] INFO   - Sending request to: http://example.com/service.endpoint
2011-08-16 16:39:36,334 [STP OrderPool Thread #0] ERROR  - Exception
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HL.Services.Blackbird.LondonBestxHub.Reuters.Execute.MakeRequest(String serviceName, StringBuilder postParams)
2011-08-16 16:39:57,381 [STP OrderPool Thread #0] INFO  - MakeRequest call completed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various possibilities here - DNS lookups, proxies etc.

I would suggest you install [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) on the problematic machine, and look at *exactly* what's going on - that should show you where the problem is.

(As an aside, I would strongly advise you to use `using` statements for writers, streams, `WebResponses` etc. I don't think it's the problem here, but if something happens such that you fail to close a `WebResponse`, you can end up with timeouts for future requests to the same host due to connection pooling.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Jon. I do not believe it to be DNS, as the problem occurrs after the exception is raised indicating there was a 500 error, and before the request completes. Problems accessing the service endpoint I would expect to manifest in delays achieving a response from the server, and this is now what I am seeing.

Comment: That should read "not what I'm seeing", rather than "now what I'm seeing"... :)

Comment: @rvxnet: It's not clear what you mean - what timing logs do you have? Where are you seeing the delay, exactly?

Comment: The delay exists between the two lines: "Exception raised with request..." and "MakeRequest() has completed"

Comment: @rvxnet: I find that hard to believe. If you log the current time *directly after* that "Exception with request riased" line and *directly before* the "MakeRequest has completed" line, you really see a 15 second gap? I don't mean to doubt you, but I've never experienced *anything* like that before, and it sounds mad to me. Can you update your example to show the code you used to observe where the delay occurred?

Comment: Hard to believe, yet true! Hence why I am posting this on here. This is a slightly modified version of my original source - as I'm using Log4Net to monitor the timestamps in the full version. Concept remains the same however.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include a chunk of logs for a real request as it was observed yesterday afternoon.

Comment: @rvxnet: That log doesn't *quite* show the same information. It's possible that it took a long time to capture the stack trace of the exception etc. 15 seconds seems huge, but it's still just about possible. Assuming you can reproduce this reliably, can you put  extra log statements directly before and after the "Exception with request raised" log? If my hunch is accurate, you'll see that the timestamp of the "Exception with request" line is close to the timestamp of the line before.

Comment: @JonSkeet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2566/discussion-between-rvxnet-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Jon: I believe your hunch is correct! I have added an extra line above my exception logging line to the effect of "about to capture exception". This is logged instantly, then the delay occurrs actually writing the entry contain the exception dump. Now, I guess my next question is: What could be causing this difference in delay between two different machines?

Comment: @rvxnet: Unsure. Can you get the same effect by logging a simple line, then just calling `ex.ToString()` (not logging), and then logging another line? If you make a *second* request, does that have the same problem, or is it a one-time hit? I've seen exceptions take a long time to gather information when debugging, but not quite like this...

Comment: The delay does seem consistent across multiple requests within the same instance. So it seems that this is something to do with how the exception is gathering information, rather than anything to do with the request itself?

Comment: @rvxnet: So within the same process, it's always taking a long time? That's weird. Did you try my test of just calling ToString and seeing if that takes a long time? It may also be worth seeing if there's network traffic while it's doing that...